# AutoTrigger a method on Server using Timer - Performance

Tags: java, server

I have a webservice deployed on a weblogic server. Whenever any client instance hits that webservice, I have to store the clients details and send mail to the client every 24 hours until the client takes the required action.

So in order to send mail every 24 hours, I've written a timer code, that should call the method to send mail every 24 hours.

**My question is :** Since the code is on server, And there can be 100s of clients that will hit my webservice and start their own timer instance. **So does having these multiple timer instance(say 100 or more) affect the server performance?**

If yes, please suggest an alternative code I can use to trigger mails sending every 24 hours after the webservice is hit.

**Update - My Code**

```
public static final Map<String, Timer> userDeactivationPendingMap = new HashMap();

    @GET
    @Path("/check-deactivation-status/{username}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String checkDeactivationStatus(@PathParam("username") final String username) {

        String returnJsonString = "Email has been sent to IProc team to take further actions on it.";

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask dailyTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                hitEmailSendingApi(username, "abc@test.com");
            }
        };

        // schedule the task to run starting now and then every day...
        timer.schedule(dailyTask, 0l, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

        userDeactivationPendingMap.put(username, timer);

        return returnJsonString;
    }

    @Path("/initializeUserDeactivationRequest")    @GET

    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String deactivateUser(@QueryParam("username") String username) {

        //code to deactivate user

        //Cancelling timer
        Timer timer = userDeactivationPendingMap.get(username);

        timer.cancel();

        return "<h4>User Deactivated Successfully!!<h4>";
    }

    private void hitEmailSendingApi(String username, String iprocTeamMailAddress) {

        String domain = RequestFilter.getRequest().getRequestURL().toString();
        String contextPath = RequestFilter.getRequest().getContextPath();
        String serverURL = domain.substring(0, domain.indexOf(contextPath));

        String servletPath = RequestFilter.getRequest().getServletPath();
        serverURL = serverURL + contextPath + servletPath;

        EmailSender.sendEmail(iprocTeamMailAddress, "Action Required: Clear User's Pending Requisitions for Account Deactivation", "Hi Team"
                + ",\n\n A new request for user deactivation has been raised by " + username + ".\n\n"
                + "Once all the requisitions are cleared, please press on below link for deactivating the user.\n"
                + serverURL + "/deactivate-account/initializeUserDeactivationRequest?username=" + (username));
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to suggest alternative code if you do not provide your code.

Also, yes obviously doing more things at once imposes more load to the server which affects the server's performance. The question should be "is the performance affection severe enough to warrant a change?" Without seeing your code I would say: No it does not. But that's just a blind guess and should be taken with a couple grains of salt.

Comment: @Ben Please see the updated question.

Comment: This looks about as performant as you can get and certainly does not warrant optimization as long as you don't experience issues with it. The only thing I could think about currently would be using `scheduleAtFixedRate` over `schedule` with the same `Date firstTime` object as the scheduler here tries to keep all of those in sync and executing at the same time (leading to your mails being sent at the same time each day). In praxis it will probably not change anything over using `schedule` but it will also certainly not hurt.

Comment: I suggest you to don't have multiple timers. Instead you may have only one timer with for example a 5 minutes timeout period. So every 5 minutes check which clients reached the 24 hour deadline (may be by a query to db) and send emails to them. So your web service should not start new timers for every new request, only save the request time for them in db and let the timer do the rest.

Comment: @Ben But in that the timer will be for infinite duration. Never getting stopped or cancelled. As the requests will keep pouring. So is an infinite timer good for performance?

Comment: @STaefi Can there be a scheduled timer for a particular time of the day? Say everyday at 12PM, the timer should trigger the mails?

Comment: @HarshitaSethi: It depends how you are managing to create timers. For example EJB3.1 timers support a wide range of patterns to schedule the times.

Comment: @STaefi What are your views on the performance of the server with this infinite Timer. As in the timer will never be cancelled, Will be running all the time on the server. Do you think it will affect the server performance?

Comment: @HarshitaSethi: There is only one timer running on the server and it's so light because it does nothing than creating a pulse for example every 5 minute or every hour or so. Your actual business should be implemented in a Stateless Session Bean which is being called from that timer. So nothing to worry about the timers here. Then you may work to increase the performance of that Session Bean's code execution.